Proof of a theorem in david m. Burton's number theory

Theorem 8.6: if p is a prime number and $d\mid p-1$ then there exist exactly $\phi(d)$ numbers modulu p such that the order of those modulu p is d

He signed the amount of numbers with the order d mod p $\psi(d)$ and then proved $$(1) \qquad p-1=\sum_{d\mid p-1}\psi(d)=\sum_{d\mid p-1}\phi(d)$$
Now this part was clear to me, but then he said:

it is needed now to prove that $\forall d\mid p-1 \quad \psi(d) \le\phi(d) $, because from that inequality and (1) we get $\psi(d) =\phi(d) \ne0$

After that he provides a clear proof to the above Statement but I didn't understand how the above statement implies what he said it implies???

If any of the inequalities $\psi(d)\le\phi(d)$ were strict, then summing them would yield $\sum \psi(d)<\sum\phi(d)$ strictly, a contradiction.

Duplicate, please delete once all is clear.
